# Run command with space characters in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, imagemagick

I have a file that contains a list of files:

```
02 of Clubs.eps
02 of Diamonds.eps
02 of Hearts.eps
02 of Spades.eps
...
```

I am attempting to mass-convert these to png format in several sizes. The script I am using to do this is:

```
while read -r line
do
    for i in 80 35 200
    do
        convert $(sed 's/ /\\ /g' <<< Cards/${line}) -size ${i}x${i} ../img/card/$(basename $(tr ' ' '_' <<< ${line} | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]') .eps)_${i}.png;
    done
done < card_list.txt
```

However, this doesn't work, apparently trying to split on each word, resulting in the following error output:

```
convert: unable to open image `Cards/02\': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2514.
convert: no decode delegate for this image format `Cards/02\' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/532.
convert: unable to open image `of\': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2514.
convert: no decode delegate for this image format `of\' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/532.
convert: unable to open image `Clubs.eps': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2514.
```

If I change the convert to an echo the result looks right and if I copy a line and run it myself in the shell it works fine:

```
convert Cards/02\ of\ Clubs.eps -size 80x80 ../img/card/02_of_clubs_80.png
convert Cards/02\ of\ Clubs.eps -size 35x35 ../img/card/02_of_clubs_35.png
convert Cards/02\ of\ Clubs.eps -size 200x200 ../img/card/02_of_clubs_200.png
convert Cards/02\ of\ Diamonds.eps -size 80x80 ../img/card/02_of_diamonds_80.png
convert Cards/02\ of\ Diamonds.eps -size 35x35 ../img/card/02_of_diamonds_35.png
convert Cards/02\ of\ Diamonds.eps -size 200x200 ../img/card/02_of_diamonds_200.png
convert Cards/02\ of\ Hearts.eps -size 80x80 ../img/card/02_of_hearts_80.png
convert Cards/02\ of\ Hearts.eps -size 35x35 ../img/card/02_of_hearts_35.png
convert Cards/02\ of\ Hearts.eps -size 200x200 ../img/card/02_of_hearts_200.png
convert Cards/02\ of\ Spades.eps -size 80x80 ../img/card/02_of_spades_80.png
```

**UPDATE:**

Just adding quotes (see below) has the same result as the above, where I had been using sed to add backslashes

```
convert '"'Cards/${line}'"' -size ${i}x${i} ../img/card/$(basename $(tr ' ' '_' <<< ${line} | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]') .eps)_${i}.png;
```

I've tried both double and single quotes

Comment: There's no way for me to try but I think you need to put "" on the $(sed ...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shell works fine with lines split, and using variables to make the code readable - avoiding horizontal scroll bars here...

```
while read -r line
do
    for i in 80 35 200
    do
        epsfile="Cards/$line"
        pngbase=$(basename "$line" .eps | tr ' A-Z' '_a-z')
        pngfile="../img/card/${pngbase}_${i}.png"
        convert "$epsfile" -size ${i}x${i} "$pngfile"
    done
done < card_list.txt
```

If you have to deal with filenames that contain spaces, you need to enclose the names in double quotes when passing them to commands.  The complex code with all the file manipulation scrunched into a single line is near-enough impossible to read.  You can do the whole of the transliteration in a single command, as shown above, which also simplifies things.

Even though 80 characters isn't a hard limit, it is worth keeping it as a rough limit, because if the line is much longer, it probably isn't readable, and code must be readable to be maintainable.

Comment: If I read the original right, pngbase should be built from $line, not $epsfile; otherwise, looks good to me.

Comment: @Gordon: since `basename` removes the `Card/` prefix to `$epsfile`, I don't think it actually matters, but yes, you're correct that the original code worked off the value of `$line`.  I'll bring the code into line.

Comment: @ʞɔıu: thanks for the edit - sorry I missed the '_${i}' inserted into the PNG file name.

Answer (score 2):

Simply quote filenames with blanks or other special characters.  Also, You do not need the sed, or tr.

See bash docs on "Variable Substitution" (pps 21-22, bash Pocket Reference, O'Reilly)

Simplify the loop by putting the conversion logic into a function

```
# cvt file size 
cvt() {
 infile="$1"  # quote in case filename has blanks
 size="$2"
 outfile="${infile/ /_}"              # replace spaces with underlines
 outfile="${outfile##*/}"             # remove any directory path
 outfile="${outfile,,*}"              # downcase the filename
 outfile="${outfile%.eps}_$size.png"  # remove suffix, add size and new suffix
 ( set -x ; convert "Cards/$infile" -size ${size}x$size "../img/card/$outfile" )
}

while read -r line ; do
  for i in 80 35 200 ; do
    cvt "$line" $i
  done
done < card_list.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Like Hai said, enclose your file name in "". Otherwise the shell reads the space on the line as a delimiter for the next argument.

eg.

```
VAR="test file"
cat $VAR # outputs the contents of 'test', followed by the contents of 'file'

cat "$VAR" # outputs the contents of 'test file'
```

edit:
In short your problem is using sed to escape the spaces. It's not doing what you're thinking it's doing -- it's producing the literal string "02\ of\ Clubs.eps" not "02 of Clubs.eps". Replace the sed part with just "Cards/${line}".

Comment: You have a second instance where you use $line. That will also need to be enclosed in "". convert $(sed 's/ /\\ /g' <<< __Cards/${line})__ -size ${i}x${i} ../img/card/$(basename $(tr ' ' '_' <<< __${line}__ | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]') .eps)_${i}.png;

Comment: Ah, I don't use shell scripts often. In short your problem is using sed to escape the spaces. It's not doing what you're thinking it's doing -- it's producing the literal string "02\ of\ Clubs.eps" not "02 of Clubs.eps". Replace the sed part with just "Cards/${line}".